# How to generate RestController classes

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, intellij-idea, code-generation, spring-restcontroller

I am writing Spring Boot application in intelliJ-IDEA, and have database with many tables on MySQL server. I generated Entity classes from database (Hibernate).

Is there a way to generate Repository classes from Entity classes, and then to generate RestController classes from Repository classes?

Or is there a way to generate RestController classes directly from Entity classes or from database?

I don't want to write all that RestController classes for whole database.

Comment: You can use spring-boot-starter-data-rest starter here it is explained http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-intro

Answer (score 2):

Telosys code generator (http://www.telosys.org) does this kind of job.

It uses the database schema to create a lightweight model that is used to generate the Java code.
There are some predefined templates available on GitHub (https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3) for JPA, POJO, REST controllers, Spring MVC, etc The advantage is that everything is generated with a single tool.

You can use the command line tool (http://www.telosys.org/cli.html) or the Eclipse plugin (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/telosys-tools)

Some interesting articles about code generation with Telosys :

- https://modeling-languages.com/telosys-tools-the-concept-of-lightweight-model-for-code-generation/
- https://dzone.com/articles/telosys-a-code-generation-tool-by-laurent-guerin